# pyautogui don't recognize variables

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

Its a app with tkinter to move the mouse where the coordinates indicate, so I used normal variables, but for some reason it does't work, the mouse just don't move and non error apear. I tried take out the variables and use normal numbers and it worked fine, why with the variables it bugs? And what is the error?

```
    coord1= Entry(win, width=10)
    coord1.place(x=300, y=125)
    coord2= Entry(win, width=10)
    coord2.place(x=400, y=125)

    b = coord2.get()
    c = coord1.get()
    d = int(c,0)
    e = int(b,0)
    pyautogui.click(d, e)
```

Comment: What do you expect to get from entries that are just created?  You should get empty strings and `int(...)` will raise exception.

Comment: sorry, but what are entries just created?

Comment: `coord1` and `coord` are the two just created entries.

Comment: Ok, so what do I do?

Comment: It really depends on your program design.

Comment: The mouse doesn’t move, is it even possible to make it move like that?

Comment: If you want to move the mouse cursor, use `moveTo(d, e)` instead.

Comment: Ok, I will test if it works with moveTo, I haven’t  tried it

Comment: I tested around 10 times and it didn’t work

Comment: `moveTo()` works fine for me. Do you still using the same logic of the posted code? As I said in previous comment, the posted code does not work.

Comment: yes it does not work, it is the problem, it is the same logic, but with moveTo instead of click

Comment: You need to call those `.get()` and `moveTo(...)` in, for example, a callback of button.

Comment: can you post the code that you did, to compare, if youre code worked, maybe I can understand what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you get the values of the two `Entry` widgets right after they are created, you should get empty strings as the user has not input anything.  So `int(c, 0)` will fail with exception.

You should do the move in, for example, the callback of a button so that user can input values into the two `Entry` widgets before doing the move.

Also if you want to move the mouse cursor, you should use `pyautogui.moveTo(...)` instead of `pyautogui.click(...)`.

Below is an simple example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('500x200')

tk.Label(win, text='X:').place(x=295, y=125, anchor='ne')
coord1 = tk.Entry(win, width=10)
coord1.place(x=300, y=125)

tk.Label(win, text='Y:').place(x=395, y=125, anchor='ne')
coord2 = tk.Entry(win, width=10)
coord2.place(x=400, y=125)

# label for showing error when user input invalid values
label = tk.Label(win, fg='red')
label.place(x=280, y=80, anchor='nw')

def move_mouse():
    label.config(text='')
    try:
        x = int(coord1.get().strip(), 0)
        y = int(coord2.get().strip(), 0)
        pyautogui.moveTo(x, y) # move the mouse cursor
    except ValueError as e:
        label.config(text=e) # show the error

tk.Button(win, text='Move Mouse', command=move_mouse).place(relx=0.5, rely=1.0, y=-10, anchor='s')

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: bealtiful, thank you, if I had 15 points I would give a up vote